# I am not able to access variable 'dps' declare in index.js within index.html , using npm start

Tags: node.js, electron

I am not able to access variable 'dps' declare in index.js within index.html , using npm start(for starting electron app)
I am able to access my sql and get data in index.js and i want to show that on index.html (used nodeJs and Electron)
'dps' refers to js object which has mysql data

//My index.js file has

```
var app = require('app'); 
var dps = [{x:1,y:2}];
// Module to create native browser window.
var BrowserWindow = require('browser-window');
var mainWindow = null;
var dps = [{x:1,y:2}];
var mysql = require('mysql');

// Quit when all windows are closed.
app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform != 'darwin') {
    app.quit();
  }
});

app.on('ready', function () {

  // Create the browser window.
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
  mainWindow.loadUrl('file://' + __dirname + '/index.html');
  // Open the devtools.
  // mainWindow.openDevTools();
  // Emitted when the window is closed.
  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    // Dereference the window object, usually you would store windows
    // in an array if your app supports multi windows, this is the time
    // when you should delete the corresponding element.
    mainWindow = null;
  });
});


//My html file

<html>
<head>
<!--<script type="text/javascript" src = "index.js"/>-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
  alert(dps); --- not getting dps value here(/anywhere in html)
</head>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code in index.html runs in a different process (usually called the Renderer process) than your in index.js (which runs in the Main process). Furthermore, your index.js file is a module, therefore, even if the two were run by the same process, you'd have to export your `dps` variable or make it a global variable like `global.dps` (however, that's a bad practice!).

There are a number of ways to share date between the Main and the Renderer process; Electron provides the `ipcMain`, `ipcRenderer` and `remote` modules for that purpose; you can also pass data from Main to the Renderer using URL encoded parameters (but this doesn't help you if the data changes); finally, you can use any other form of IPC (e.g., send messages over a socket, use shared memory or shared files, etc.) -- but it's a good idea to start with Electron's `ipc` or `remote` modules.

Having said that, in your case, the [consensus](https://discuss.atom.io/t/electron-app-database-file-structure-code-structure/16491) seems to be not to use the Main process for DB access only to then pass the information on to the Renderer, but rather access the DB directly from the Renderer; that way you won't have to worry about IPC at all (at least in this case).

Comment: Thanx for your guidance mate :)